# Solve matrix equation $\|I-2x A + x^2 B\|=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices, and $x$ is a positive real number, how do I solve the following equation for $x$ and operator norm $\|\cdot\|$?

$$\|I-2x A + x^2 B\|=1$$

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ is operator norm, edited question. For solution, I'm can see that the x=smallest generalized eigenvalue of (2A,B) solves it for specific matrices arising in my application, looking to show this more rigorously

Comment: $I-2xA + x^2 B \le (1-2x \lambda_n(A) +x^2 \lambda_1(B))I$ so for small $x$ the norm is less than one, hence a positive solution exists.

Comment: @JCAA The question assumes $A,B$ positive definite symmetric.